# How to reverse proxy grafana on ingress without using helm?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-ingress

I wanna reverse proxy grafana. I am not using domain to access ingress, instead i use the node's IP. I am using rewrite target to do the job but, it doesnt work. It is always redirect the app to /login without prefix /grafana (404 error). Expected url is /grafana/login.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: nginx-example-grafana
  namespace: grafana
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress-grafana
  namespace: grafana
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example-grafana
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /grafana(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: grafana
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Comment: As per the official [documentation](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/),you can Include the sub path at the end of the “root\_url” in the Grafana configuration file and set “serve\_from\_sub\_path” to “true”.

Comment: It works, thank youu

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since the offered suggestion has helped you in overcoming the issue, I have converted the comment as a response to have greater visibility to community members. Could you please provide feedback in it as explained in [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/) from Grafana Labs,you can Include the sub path at the end of the `root_url` in the Grafana configuration file and set `serve_from_sub_path` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. It is the expected behavior with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` annotation. I will redirect to the second capture group of the regular expression of your path, therefore changing `/grafana/login` to `/login` since `/login` matches the second capture group of your regex.

I would simply remove the redirection, and leave the path to `/grafana`.

Comment: still doesnt work, i dont know why it still redirect the url without prefix. I found the workaround by insert the required value as suggested by @kiran-kotturi